# Legacy data migration to Always on Availability group database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, availability-groups, migration

In our application there is a data conversion process that brings all the legacy data to the production database.

Since our database is on availability group and the migration might bring 100GB + worth of data, my plan was to remove all the secondary replica from the availability group and then set the primary database offline.

Restore the production database into a staging server, then complete the migration/conversion and then restore it back to the Production and syn all the secondary replicas

Please advise if there is a better way to do the migration.

Answer (score 3):

> my plan was to remove all the secondary replica from the availability group and then set the primary database offline.
>   Restore the production database into a staging server, then complete the migration/conversion

This seems like a really reasonable plan.  You'd likely have lots of issues trying to load 100 GB+ of data to the AG quickly, especially if they are sync replicas.  So this avoids the network and redo bottlenecks you would have likely encountered.

> and then restore it back to the Production and syn all the secondary replicas

It looks like you're on SQL Server 2014, so this also makes sense - as your only option at this point would be to do "manual seeding" (restore the database and log on the secondary replica).

If you were on SQL Server 2016 or higher, I warn against using "automatic seeding" with such a large amount of data.